# Where are all the stars located?

Tags: the-talos-principle

In The Talos Principle, there are stars hidden around the levels.  The game tells you when you're missing stars, but it doesn't give you any indication of where in the level to find them.

So, where in each level are the stars?  I'm more interested in **where they are** *(like, which puzzle)*, not **how to get them** - I still want to solve the puzzles, I just don't want to spend hours looking them.

Comment: [A quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=talos+principle+stars+locations&gws_rd=cr&ei=F8PGVIGTLMX7UvqLghA) can help you a lot I think. I haven't played the game. Yet![waiting for my finals to end] but [3rd link](http://gameswiki.net/the-talos-principle-world-a-all-stars-locations-guide/) looks promising.

Comment: @Lafexlos: I am looking for hints, not solutions.  *(though a complete answer would have the solutions in spoilers :P)*

Comment: I tried to edit my comment to say "looking at your rep, you probably know what a google search is. So sorry for jumping on, way too early" but that was too late to edit. Anyway, let's allow my stupid comment stay there for guys like me.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

First of all. There are 30 stars at The Talos Principle as far as I know:

1. There are 27 stars in the halls (A,B,C).
2. There are 2 stars in the main world - the one with the tower.
3. There is 1 star in the messenger places.

*Then, second, please, don't think that knowing exact locations of each star will save you from exploring, often you still need to search for instruments (jammers, cubes, etc.) to get the star and it is essentially the same task. Even more, I think this game is about exploring. Even during the sigil puzzles you need to find a jammer, you need to find a position for connector, you need to find the sigil at the end, etc.*

But anyway, in the following I give hints, which are aimed to reduce: a) process big area exploration, b) "looking for I don't know what", c) trials and errors when you trying to jump over a wall. After
   you read all hints you will face a usual sigil-type puzzle. But be
   carefull, some of this hints makes the rest of the star-puzzle
   trivial.

When you read the hints note that:

- "Open world" is all world excluding the puzzle areas, sometimes it is inner
  area (surrounded by puzzles), sometimes outer area. sometimes both.
- Right/left/front/back are given respectively to your position when you enter a puzzle or teleport to a world.
- "Hidden area" usually means an area completely surrounded by walls/fences. Often you can look inside if you jump.

The hints:

1. A1. Exact location:

   > Open world. Forward from the teleport to another puzzle area. Twice to the left to L-shaped puzzle area. It is in hidden area behind the fence to the right from the puzzle door.

   Crucial secret:

   > There is a switch somewhere.
2. A2. Exact location:

   > Open world near the teleport. Behind a small wall in bushes to the right.

   Crucial secret:

   > You can take a key outside from a puzzle.

   Crucial secret2:

   > There is a door in the backwards direction from the teleport.
3. A3.1. Exact location:

   > "A Bit Tied Up". Right front corner, near the sigil.
4. A3.2. Exact location:

   > Open space, under ground near the teleport.

   Crucial secret:

   > You can change time on the clock.

   Crucial secret 2:

   > You will need to know what is HEX and what is ASCII.
5. A4. Exact location:

   > "Push it further", in the corner. Look for a narrow path near a wall.

   Crucial secret:

   > There is a hidden connector on the top of a column (or a tree in older version of the game), that is nearby.
6. A5.1. Exact location:

   > "Friendly crossfire". Right front corner, where the black ball was.
7. A5.2. Exact location:

   > "Things to do with 2 boxes". Behind a wall at hidden area at back left corner.

   Crucial secret:

   > There is a switch somewhere.
8. A6. Exact location:

   > Open world in hidden area to the left, between 2 puzzle areas.

   Crucial secret:

   > There is an object in the open world.
9. A7. Exact location:

   > "Two Pesky Little Buzzers" Left back corner.

   Crucial secret:

   > You can shoot laser though the violet barrier.
10. B1. Exact location:

    > "Something about a star". Right in the center.
11. B2. Exact location:

    > "The Tomb", behind right statue, you can see a path from outside.

    Crucial secret:

    > You can come in from the inside of the puzzle.
12. B3. Exact location:

    > "Blown Away". In a hidden area right near of the door (to the left).

    Crucial secret:

    > You can level up a bit one of the connectors at another puzzle.
13. B4.1. Exact location:

    > "Right angle", hidden area near the front wall, you can see fan.
14. B4.2. Exact location:

    > Open world, in the Sphinx.

    Crucial secret:

    > There is a hidden source and receiver in the open world.

    Crucial secret 2:

    > You can get one of the puzzle-connectors outside.
15. B5. Exact location:

    > In a middle of the open world, on the top of the spire.

    Crucial secret:

    > You can take things outside from puzzles.
16. B7.1. Exact location:

    > Open world, at the top of the big arch structure in front of the big pyramid.

    Crucial secret:

    > You can take things outside from puzzles.
17. B7.2. Exact location:

    > "Bouncing side by side". Front left corner.
18. C1. Exact location:

    > Open world, at ruins behind the puzzle areas, behind a barrier. You can see it easily if you explore the ruins a little bit.

    Crucial secret:

    > You can find a connector in the open world.
19. C2. Exact location:

    > "A Ditch and a fence", at the left front corner, behind a wall.
20. C3. Exact location:

    > "Weathertop", at the left front corner, you can see it when you solve the puzzle.
21. C4.1. Exact location:

    > "Outbliette", behind the wall on the right.
22. C4.2. Exact location:

    > "Throne room", near the front wall.
23. C5.1. Exact location:

    > "Time flights", hidden area in front of the recorder.
24. C5.2. Exact location:

    > "Close and jammed", hidden area right after first barrier on the left.
25. C5.3. Exact location:

    > "Dumbwaiter", behind the front wall.

    Crucial secret:

    > There are two solutions. At the simple you can use locations of 3 puzzles. At the hard you can take a connector inside to the open world.
26. C6. Exact location:

    > "Seven doors of the recording", at the right back corner, just follow the barriers.
27. C7. Exact location:

    > "Dead Man's switch", around a corner, near the front wall.
28. MW1. Exact location:

    > A small building behind the tower.

    Crucial secret:

    > You can take connectors outside from the tower. But you can't solve it until you reach the hall C.
29. MW2. Exact location:

    > Tower's 3rd floor, on the left from the door.

    Crucial secret:

    > There is a hole in the roof.
30. MP1. Exact location:

    > Messenger place at C hall, on a floating iland.

    Crucial secret:

    > Everything you need is right in front of you. Go for it.

I don't put here exact solutions intentionally, I think a player should solve puzzles by himself. But if you really want full solutions you can see all of them, for example, in [this 33 minutes guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRhBlw1A4_c) on youtube.

Comment: I know I can view how many stars are in each level, but I'm more interested in where they are within each level *(so I can spend time figuring out how to get them, rather than trying to find them)*.  I know many of them are inside puzzle-areas, but I've found some outside the puzzle areas as well, and searching every square inch of every huge level does not sound like fun.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, I added here all crucial hints for all stars. Hope this is enough.:)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Trying to search a puzzle zone for a single star after having solved all the puzzles and having **not** spotted it is a right pain.  I'm enjoying the exploration, but having to back track over areas I thought I'd explored isn't all that much fun.